# Linux Mint install freeze

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation, grub2, gpu

I'd like to try Linux Mint 18.3 after experiencing trouble with ubuntu16.04 on a razr stealth rz09 with gtx1060 gpu .    I made a live install usb , boot it and go thru the install screens, and invariably hit a freeze after defining timezones and starting the actual install ('copying files...').  I tried:

disabling UEFI in favor of legacy in bios

with/wo network, with/wo 3rd party installs

OEM install

doing, at CLI from a terminal in live installer:

```
gksu live-installer
```

at CLI from comaptibility-mode boot:

```
gksu live-installer
```

I get freezes in all cases (except the gksu command which gives no output and doesnt appear to do anything). 
If anyone has any hints I'd appreciate it , otherwise the show is effectively stopped and I will go back to ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the guide [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=122257) involving adding the params

```
nomodeset xforcevesa
```

to the grub boot script (at the end of the line starting with 'linux' )  did the trick. The install finally occurs, hallelujah  and i reboot, once again put those params into the grub, and mint then boots from disk and not usb.  Then install the video drivers as per the guide and reboots are now fine without grub modification. I'm currrently waiting on cuda and hope to have cuda and cudnn running as well; currently at least nvidia-smi shows hardware which is further than I was before.   With the nvidia drivers  up under mint, some other stuff started working that hadnt been on linux, e.g. external monitors and rebooting without freezing. 
This guide might also work for an ubuntu install but in meantime mint seems to have no drawbacks as compared to ubuntu.